# Probability of drawing at least 2 aces out of a deck of 32

Tags: probability

This problem is a little tricky because it has to be solved using only fractions and not any advanced formulas.

The deck has 32 cards and 4 aces. What is the probability of drawing **at least** 2 aces when 3 cards are drawn from the deck and not put back.

The solution given is:
$$
\frac{43}{1240}=0.034677
$$

I tried using (draw two aces, then a different card and multiply by the number of ways this can be drawn):

$$
\frac{4}{32}*\frac{3}{31}*\frac{28}{30}*3=\frac{42}{1240}=0.033871
$$

That answer is the same as drawing excactly 2 aces and just below the sought-after answer.

I just can't figure out what missing probability I have to add to find the missing 1/1240.

Comment: I believe the card you are looking for is "aces", not "asses"

Comment: Oh my god my English is bad :(

Comment: To answer your question, you are missing the case that drawing 3 aces should be counted also. So missing probability is $$\frac{4}{32}*\frac{3}{31}*\frac{2}{30}=\frac{1}{1240}$$

Comment: But when I calculate that: (4/32)*(3/31)*(2*30)*3 I get 3/1240 instead of 1/1240. But aren't there also 3 ways of drawing three aces?

Comment: Here are the ways of drawing $2$ aces and $1$ not ace: AAN, ANA, NAA. So you multiply the answer by $3$. Now, the only way of drawing $3$ aces would be AAA. So you do not multiply your answer by $3$.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense. Why don't you make an answer so I can accept. My math book does such a bad job at describing this, that it would be good to keep this in the stackexchange archive. Sometimes the easy things are really confusing. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The no. of ways in which one can get at least 2 aces in 3 draws is
(no. of ways he can get 2 aces) + (no. of ways he can get 3 aces)
= (AAN + NAA + ANA) + AAA
= (AAN).3 + AAA
= (4/32 ∗ 3/31 ∗ 28/30).3 + (4/32 ∗ 3/31 ∗ 2/30)
= 42/1240 + 1/1240 = 43/1240.